# Is it possible to exploit Teamviewer shared clipboard to send malicious code to Guest?

Tags: windows, security, clipboard, teamviewer

Recently, while I was using TeamViewer I noticed that the clipboard is shared between host and guest.

If user A allow user B to connect, when user A copies something user B has it on his clipboard, and the same thing happens if user B copies something.

I know that clipboard is not only text, but it can hold a lot of different types of data.

My question is: Can user B copy some content (that contains malicious code) that will be executed on user A PC when user A paste that content?

(I'm not interested in writing viruses, I want only know if this is possible or not.)

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, yes it is possible.

Comment: Can you explain it with a longer answer?